# Correct approach for RequestParam in REST controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a REST controller containing multiple endpoints. Each controller method accepts some RequestParams, the number of which can vary between methods. Is it a good approach to create a model class to serve as a superset of all the RequestParams and for each method, use only those attributes that are needed? Or should I define all the parameters explicitly for each method and not use the Model class?

If the first approach is the right one, is there a way to validate individual attributes in the model class for each controller method?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to create a model class then you may make request as POST request.

There is another way as pass all the requestParam as Map.

The documentation is as below how to pass the Map as requestParam:

https://reversecoding.net/spring-mvc-requestparam-binding-request-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

The way to pass params as a map for Http GET method looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/detail")
public MyDto getMyDto(@RequestParam Map<String, String> queryParams) {
...
}
```

And in your URL you will do this:

```
http://myHost:8080/detail?param1=10&param2=Downing
```

In your code you will get a map; `{"param1":10, param2:"Downing"}`

For POST method the code on the server-side looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/detail")
public MyDto getMyDto(@RequestBody Map<String, String> queryParams) {
...
}
```

The difference is that annotation `@RequestParam` is replaced with `@RequestBody`